# Fabulous Wealth as Sultan

Tags: tales-of-arabian-nights

**Does being *Sultan* bypass the special requirements for being *Fabulously* Wealthy?**

When gaining the Sultan status, a player automatically moves their wealth counter directly to *fabulous* (the highest option).  However, being *Fabulously* Wealthy also has a requirement that the player must possess a treasure.  Does being Sultan supersede this rule, or would a Sultan without any treasure be immediately moved back down to *Princely* regardless of their status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would it? Nothing in the Sultan status says you can't lose wealth. It simply raises your wealth like so many other effects, and the rules clearly limit your wealth to Princely if you have no treasure.